# How to manipulate functions?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, performance-tuning

This is probably a simple question, I have matrix a , and I construct b from a by adding a variable to the first column. b is a function of variable d, and now I need to do mathematical calculation on the first and third column of b and save it as c. c is also a function of variable d.

```
a = Table[{RandomReal[{1, 4}], RandomReal[{1, 4}], 
RandomReal[{1, 4}]}, {i, 1, 5}];
b[d_] := MapAt[# + d &, A, {{All, 1}}];
c[d_] := Table[
 Sqrt[(b[d][[i]][[1]])^2 + (b[d][[i]][[3]])^2], {i, 1, 5}];
```

The way I did it works, but I am looking for a more efficient way to play with functions which are being used in other lines of my program (like of I need to have also functions g[d], k[d],...). Can anybody help me to do this type of calculation faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear[a, b, c, d, m];
a = Array[m, {5, 3}];
b = SubsetMap[# + d &, a, {All, 1}];
c = Sqrt[# . #] & /@ b[[All, {1, 3}]]
```

[image]

Or

```
a = Array[m, {5, 3}];
Sqrt[(#1 + d)^2 + #2^2] & @@@ a[[All, {1, 3}]]
```